# Python - How to split variable based on certain range

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to split a certain variable to 2 new variables based on its range.

The variable, x, has majority of its data between 0-1, while the rest goes up to 50. It makes sense to change this to a dummy variable so that all values between 0-1 are 0 and all values greater than 1 are 1. 
For example, if I wanted to set a dummy variable for a specific number, I could do train['sppct'].replace([5,9], [0,1], inplace=True)

This would replace all values of 5 with a 0, and all values of 9 with a 1. I want to replace all values between 0-1 with 0, and all values greater than 1 with a 1.

Comment: Do you have any code that attempts to do this? As written, this is very unclear.  What datatype is `x`?

Comment: Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: I just started using python and regressing so I might butcher the explanation. But it's a dataset from excel, and there's a predictor called Percentage that are Spanish. I've called it 'sppct' in python. The response variable is Exam Results. I have it called 'er' in python. I want to change sppct so that any data value between 0 to 1 is set to a dummy variable of 0 to represent no spanish, and value greater than 1 is set to a variable of 1 to represent spanish.

Comment: For example, if I wanted to set a dummy variable for a specific number, I could do 
train['sppct'].replace([5,9], [0,1], inplace=True)
This would replace all values of 5 with a 0, and all values of 9 with a 1.
I want to replace all values between 0-1 with 0, and all values greater than 1 with a 1.